# How to add pre-rendering to VueJS using Laravel Mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, prerender

I'm having a Laravel application with a VueJS frontend as a landing page (web tool). I've noticed it shows up on Google as a blank page as the content isn't pre-rendered. I've googled and found the solutions to pre-render the HTML more complex and work intense than I expected. Is there a simple way using Laravel Mix?

Comment: It's kinda broad topic to explain here but you can get a quick start here: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/01/vue-js-prerendering-node-laravel

Comment: Hmmmm, I had a look at this one and it appeared a bit too complex. I got the feeling this one is made harder than it actually needs to be. Somehow I got the feeling there must be a simpler way to do this

Comment: Server side rendering  isn't that difficult with Laravel Vue especially, follow this tutorial: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering and honestly, avoiding the prerender plugin above will save you some time cos even in theory, it wasn't built to work with php.

Comment: Dear @spekulatius could you solve prerendering? if so, please share how you did that?

Comment: Hey @Zia, no unfortunately I didn't end up solving it. I ended up dropping VueJS for Livewire and Alpine. The whole pre-rendering isn't an issue in this case as it's BE-controlled anyways.